# How does one override the standard ootb localisation files for alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to override some ootb localisation files in alfresco by changing some wording in them. 
**Namely**: 
1. activities-list
2. invitation-service
3. activity-list
4. slingshot

So far they're located in the *"resources/alfresco/messages"* path in my project: and are bootstrapped thus:

```
<!--Overrides of ootb bundle-->
<bean id="ootb-default.overrides" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
    <property name="resourceBundles">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco.messages.activities-service</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.activity-list</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.invitation-service</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.slingshot</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you want to replace whole localisation files, or just override a few keys?

Comment: @Gagravarr replace the whole file as the changes in some are extensive.

Comment: Why not just use an AMP to zap them - put your files in the same folder and same name, then when the AMP is installed it'll clobber the built-in ones and replace them with your custom ones?

Comment: @Gagravarr That's the thing I have done exactly just this, and it doesn't override the ootb versions. Well at least I think I am doing this. "/src/main/resources/alfresco/messages/" is the path in the amp project.

Comment: Path in the AMP project doesn't matter, it's the mixture of where it ends up in the AMP, and what the AMP's `file-mapping.properties` says. Try unzipping your AMP, and see where the files are, and what the mapping say